# Is it possible for cloudformation to throw an error if it's built in the wrong region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-regions

Lamda@Edge needs to be built in the us-east-1.  Is there a way to get CloudFormation to send out an error message when someone attempts to build the stack in the wrong region?  Currently, I use conditions to only create the resources if they are in us-east-1, and not create the resources in any other region.  Since no resources get created, the Output section fails.  This has the desired effect, but it doesn't explain to the user that they are being forced into failure because they are in the wrong region.  Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up adding conditionals to the resource creation so that the resources only get created in us-east-1.  I didn't put conditionals in the outputs, so they fail if the resources aren't created.  It doesn't explain to the user as to why it failed, but at least it only builds in the correct region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Output section fails.

You can put conditions in the `Outputs` as well to **conditionally create the outputs** you only want.

But, back to your question. No, CFN will not automatically throw exceptions in your users use wrong regions, unless its not possible to create. You could use **custom resources** to error out and check your regions.

Other than that you could probably craft **IAM** policies allowing your users to lunch CFN only in regions you want.